# Symfony2 create filled Form based on two diffrent types (editAction)

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I was looking for a answer, but i never found something. .

My starting Position:
This classes / files are included

**Controller**, DataDFu1Controller.php

**Form** DataAPatientType.php ,DataDFu1Type.php

**Entity** DataAPatient, DataDFu1

**views**/**DataDfu1**/ form.html.twig

The DataDFu1Controller contains (to the overview) the indexAction, newAction and 
editAction and so on.

Both Formtypes (DataAPatientType.php ,DataDFu1Type.php) comes in one Form (look Method) this form goes to be rendered later in the form.html.twig file  for the *newAction* and the *editAction*

For the **newAction** i did it so:

```
 private function createNewForm(DataAPatient $entity)
{
    $form = $this->createForm($this->get('data_livebundle.form.dataapatienttype'), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('dataapatient_new'),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ));

    return $form->add('dFu1', new DataDFu1Type());

}
```

later the form comes rendered. . .

So first i create "DataAPatientType.php" Form and then i add the "DataDFu1Type.php" to the form.

In the view -> form.html.twig it looks like that.

for DataDFu1Type:

```
{{ form_widget(form.dFu1.fu1Examiner1)}}
```

for DataAPatientType:

```
{{ form_label(form.pSnnid, 'SNN-ID (if known)', {'label_attr':{'style':'margin-top:3px'}})}}
```

So i can get a variable or a function with the suffix 'dfu1' after the *form*.
Everything works so fine. I hope the condition are understandible till now..

**Now my Problem:**

I have to  create also an **editAction** which opend of course the same view-> form.html.twig with the filled values from a dataset (entity). In this process i don't understand how i can create the Form Object based also (DataAPatientType, DataDFu1Type) with the corresponding data. -> I'm trying to be more specific

```
 private function createEditForm(DataDFu1 $entity)
{    /*
     * This function shoud create the editform which insists 
     * DataAPatientType.php ,DataDFu1Type.php included the data from
     * $entity. I have the opportunity to get the entity for DataDFu1Type 
     * easy directly with the Primary Key and the data for DataAPatientType
     * over a Foreign Key which is safed in the $entity 
     *
     */
}
```

**So i only dont understand how i can create a Form based on two types (DataAPatientType.php ,DataDFu1Type.php) with the corresponding Data inside, that i can render it like in the newAction.**

For one Form i did it everytime like so and it works.. but for two types i tried a lot things which didnt worked. Have somebody a experiance? or a Solution for this Problem?

*the syntax of the form.html.twig isnt changeable so the form has to be rendered equivalent like in the newAction*

Example for creating a form based only on one Type and not two

```
 private function createEditForm(Event $entity)
{
    $form = $this->createForm($this->get('qcycle_eventbundle.form.eventtype'), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('event_edit', array('id' => $entity->getId())),
        'method' => 'POST'
    ));
    $form->add('preview', 'button', array('label' => 'Preview', 'attr' => array('data-preview' => 'preview')))
        ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Save Changes'))
        ->add('sendAndSave', 'submit', array('label' => 'Send Mail & Save'));

    return $form;
}
```

i really hope, that my problem and Question understandable

thanks
mjh

Comment: It is hard for me to understand. Do you want to have 2 [embeded form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/embedded.html) of the same Type in one form?

Comment: Hello, Yes its hard to describe, sorry... i need two diffrent types (DataAPatientType and DataDFu1Type with the corresponding entity in one form, so that i can render this form with the values. In the newAction you'll see that i create a form with the Type DataAPatientType and than i add the second type DataDFu1Type (both Types are FormBuilder ) to the form, so that i create one Form with 2 diffrent FormBuilder. Now i want only to do the same just not with empty forms like in a newAction, but with filled forms  (loaded data) like in an editAction. I need to load (visualize) my data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you have this form:

```
class DataAPatientType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('dFu1', new DataDFu1Type());
        $builder->add('pSnnid', 'text');
        [...]
    }
}
```

Then in create

```
$form = $this->createForm(DataAPatientType(), new DataAPatient());
```

And in edit you can simply do something like

```
private function createEditForm(DataDFu1 $entity) 
{
   $form = $this->createForm(DataAPatientType(), entity); //here the form will be "populated" by the entity data
```

So if you want to set some default value or overwrite an existing value for example, you would use

```
private function createEditForm(DataDFu1 $entity) 
{
   entity->setPSnnid('whatever')
   $form = $this->createForm(DataAPatientType(), entity); //here the form will be "populated" by the entity data
```

Comment: Hei, your solution was not directly my question, but... i can refactor my code and implement it like you showed me and than it will works:-) Thanks for your time and sorry for the lousy description.. i tried to do it clear...Thanks!